# Processing lag of 30 mins

Tags: pi-3

Have been running Kodi with no problem for over a year. Now there is some kind of lag that lasts 30 minutes before apps and libreelec will work. Tried a duplicate sd card and same problem so definitely some kind of hardware fault. Have no idea what though. Everything boots OK, kodi boots OK, but for 30mins libreelec will not open, YouTube app cannot connect, backup tools will not open etc. If I click on libreelec configuration, nothing happens, but after 30mins or so it will suddenly open by itself as if some kind of bottleneck is blocking processing.

Comment: What pi model are you using?

Comment: Pi 3 model B  V1.2

Comment: Think I've found the problem. Just as I turned it on this time Kodi loaded but an app popped up an error. I unninstalled the app and so far it's back to running OK. Will find out on next reboot. Fingers crossed.

Comment: Please share your knowledge with us and specify what app exactly is blocking kodi. Make it in an answer so everybody can see that your question has a solution.